# What is the strongest acid?

Tags: acid-base

According to Wikipedia, $\ce{HeH+}$ and fluoroantimonic acid are the strongest.

According to [a News article in Nature](http://www.nature.com/news/2004/041115/full/news041115-5.html), Carborane acid is the strongest, but Wikipedia says fluoroantimonic acid is stronger.

**Links:**

- [$\ce{HeH+}$ / Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_hydride_ion) - stating HeH+ the second most acidic
- [$\ce{HeH+}$ / Wikipedia 2nd source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compounds_of_fluorine) - stating $\ce{HeH+}$ the most acidic (see in 'Notes' section)
- [Fluoroantimonic Acid / Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid) - stating it is the strongest acid (super_acid)
- [Carborane Acid / nature.com](http://www.nature.com/news/2004/041115/full/news041115-5.html) - According to *Nature* and even Google itself, it is the strongest acid created but according to wikipedia Flouroantimonic acid is stronger.

**So, which is the strongest ?**

Comment: HeH+ is a very acidic ion, but in order to exist in a condensed form there would have to be a counterion X−. If the counterion gets protonated by the HeH+, we end up with a molecular acid HX. This then becomes only as strong as the pKa of that acid. You cannot have a bottle of HeH+ so calling it an acid is in a way kind of nonsense. I might as well talk about having a bottle of protons, which would be at least as acidic as HeH+. Note that the free proton does not exist in aqueous solution, what we call H+(aq) is really H3O+ .

Comment: What do you mean by "According to...even Google itself"? Remember that Google - a search engine - cannot itself be the source for any information.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem with this question is that the exact answer is "**it depends...**"

First off, it depends on your definition of acidity and how you measure it. Everyone seems to be using Brønstead acids (i.e. $\ce{H+}$ donors). I see two different measures in other answers:

- **[Proton affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_affinity)**: This is a gas-phase measurement of $\ce{A^{−} + H^{+} -> HA}$
- **[Hammett acidity ($H_0$)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammett_acidity_function)**: This is a solution measurement, given by $\mathrm pK_{\ce{BH^+}} - \log\left(\frac{[\ce{BH^+}]}{[\ce{B}]}\right)$

Secondly, it depends on medium as mentioned by LDC3.

- **Leveling effect**: The [solvent leveling effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveling_effect) reflects the lowest possible $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ in a particular solvent, based on the basicity of the conjugate base. So you need $\ce{HF}$ or fluorosulfuric acid to reach low $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$.

So the problem in my mind is that carboranes and fluoroantimonic acid are solution measurements, but $\ce{HeH+}$ is a gas-phase measurement. It does have the highest gas-phase proton affinity. But I'd put my money on things I can use in lab.

Incidentally, the Reed group prepared the fluorinated carborane acid this year: [*Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2014,** *53* (4), 1131–1134](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201308586). So that compound, $\ce{H(CHB11F11)}$ wins the crown for strongest solution-phase Brønstead acid (for the moment, at least).

There's also a nice review article "Myths about the Proton. The Nature of H<sup>+</sup> in Condensed Media" by the same group in [*Acc. Chem. Res.* **2013,** *46* (11), 2567–2575](https://doi.org/10.1021/ar400064q).

Comment: Well i reckon and also according to Wikipedia it has been discovered.  See helium compounds in Wikipedia.

Comment: So, is it more acidic than carborane. Also Wikipedia suggested that NeH+ has also been seen. So since Neon is even more inert so will it be the strongest acid ever known? If you read the HeH+ ion article in wikipedia, it is written it is the 2nd strongest acid known. So i was wondering!

Comment: I think it depends on your definition of "acidity" as I mention above. Are you asking about proton affinity? The linked [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_hydride_ion) gives the "strongest known acid" comment. The [list of proton affinities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_affinity_(data_page)) gives He above Ne.

Comment: So lets put it all down...which is the strongest acid regardless of medium and JUST for curiosity...?

Comment: Then I guess you'd have to go to the proton affinity definition, which points to $\ce{HeH+}$. But as I indicate in my answer, it's not like you can use it for actual chemistry.

Comment: @NeilRoy: Arguably, the strongest possible Brønsted acid is simply $\ce{H+(g)}$, i.e. a lone proton in gas phase, since anything stronger would be unstable and simply eject the proton (or break up in some other way). If this seems like a silly or trivial claim, note that species like $\ce{HeH+}$ are really just approximations of $\ce{H+}$; the helium and hydrogen in $\ce{HeH+}$ are barely bound together, and the helium, being almost completely inert, is little more than a spectator in any reaction between the proton and any Brønsted base it may react with.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen While you can argue that $\ce{H+}$ is the strongest possible Brønstead acid (its $H_0$ would be estimated at -68) it points to the "how do you define an acid" question, since you can't define a proton affinity for a proton.

Comment: You can, however, (sort of) define a proton affinity for the null molecule $\varnothing$ consisting of no nuclei or electrons; its proton affinity is trivially just 0 kJ/mol, since the "reaction" $\ce{\varnothing+H+->H+}$ does not involve any actual reaction at all, and thus no change in energy.

Answer (score 15):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superacid)
It depends on the medium.

For plasma: [helium hydride ion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium_hydride_ion)
For liquids: [fluoroantimonic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid)

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid)
Fluoroantimonic acid - $H_0$ Value = −31.3
Carborane superacid - $H_0$ Value = −18.0
100% Sulfuric Acid - $H_0$ Value = -12.0
I didn't find any information about $\ce{HeH^+}$, I guess it's because it only exist in a plasma and difficult to study.

Answer (score 11):

Carborane Acid  is the strongest acid.

The reason this is technically the world’s strongest acid is because it’s the strongest acid as a **single molecule**. Much stronger acids- the acids that melt through tables- can be created by mixing certain antimony compounds with **hydrofluoric acid ($\ce{HF}$)**. For example when you mix $\ce{SbF5}$ with $\ce{HF}$, you get an acid with a pH of **-31**.

---

Reference: [Chemistrytwig](http://chemistrytwig.com/2011/05/09/what-is-the-strongest-acid/)

Comment: What about that HeH+ ? I think it is stronger...

Comment: @neil_roy So we can say that HeH+ is strongest acid in ion form and Carborane Acid in molecule form. But it I can't figure which of them is the strongest. It seems HeH+ because it is in ion form!

Comment: yeah i agree that HeH+ is stronger also because it involves a noble gas... I was researching a li'l bit and found that NeH+ has also been found (Wikipedia : Neon Compounds) which makes it the strongest but it is so rare that...!

Comment: @NeilRoy The Ne proton affinity is lower than He. So no, NeH+ is not stronger than HeH+.

Comment: I think single molecule is an important distinction since the strongest Lewis acid is probably a very positively charged cathode ;)

Comment: @abinitio an anode maybe?